# какая функция влияет на вывод в Edit результат?

Tags: java, android

есть код, хочу что бы перемножались данные и все выводилось в отдельный эдит с возможностью редактирования. все вроде нормально но в конце не получается вывести код, если просто в текст то нормально( делал по урокам из интернета, пытался подстроить под свое приложение, но чет не выходит задумка)

```
package com.example.magictrans;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class fullcalc extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText doppoint1;
        EditText doppoint2;
        EditText doppoint3;
        EditText point4;
        double a, b, c, d;

        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fullcalc);
            //Место где объявляем значение переменных//
            doppoint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.delivery1);
            doppoint2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.delivery1);
            doppoint3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.delivery1);
            point4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point4);

            //считываем данные из EditText//
            String S1 = doppoint1.getText().toString();
            String S2 = doppoint2.getText().toString();
            String S3 = doppoint3.getText().toString();

            //преобразование текста в числа//
            a = Double.parseDouble(S1);
            b = Double.parseDouble(S2);
            c = Double.parseDouble(S3);

        // формула умножения//
            d=a*b*c;

            String point4 = Double.toString(d);
            EditText.setText(Integer.parseInt(point4));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените последние 2 строки на :

```
String result = Double.toString(d);
point4.setText(result);
```

Это будет работать только при условии, что на в ваших editText содержащими дробные числа при инициализации уже будут значения.

Хотя я бы рекомендовал сначала ознакомиться хоть с какой-то теоретической базой для разработки под android. Пока складывается ощущение что без понимания пишете.

Comment: я как бы реализовал метод ввода через цифровую клавиатуру, числа прописываются в едите вот примерно так "40.45 или 11.65"

что имеется ввиду под теорией? просто сам интерфейс я реализовал, изучаю уже на практике все + использую материалы гугла.
Я просто ставлю цель( которая была запланирована на проект) и пытаюсь по кусочкам ее реализовать в рамках микроцели

Comment: Если вы про теорию чисел, то есть что такое int float b и т.д. я в принципе знаю, поэтому флоат не использую так как нужно 2 цифры после точки.

Comment: Ну потому что вы глупость пишете. Что вы например хотите добиться строкой :EditText.setText(Integer.parseInt(point4)); Куда по вашему мнению должен вставиться результат в какой именно editText? Почему вы приводите к типу Integer строку содержащую произведение дробных чисел? Почему вы пытаетесь вставить как текст данные типа Integer.

Comment: все я понял, простите за глупые ответы. Просто делал по примеру я думал что это обертка для всех чисел. сейчас узнал что для целых только.

Comment: @Bulbash  Писать код методом научного тыка - плохая идея. Почитайте сначала литературу, например книгу Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", уже с первых глав вам станет понятно, как долго и неправильно вы бы шли к разработке "нормального человека" своим научным тыком. (Последняя редакция по Kotlin, все более ранние по Java в качестве языка разработки) Должна быть база, хотя бы, чтоб не считать тип Integer оберткой всех чисел или считать, что типу float почему то нужно именно 2 цифры после точки (это уже надо читать книги по Java) - хотя если вам не жаль своего времени ..

Comment: да если бы были полезные материалы, сперва изучал по порядку, в итоге понял что пока изучаю новое, старое выходит из головы. 
Поставил себе цель написать приложение, за 2 дня изучил разметку, стили, как создавать новые классы, как использовать слушатель онкликлистенер.
Просто на практике выходит как то проще запоминать, когда учу чисто теорию голова забивается информацией но не используется.
Просто хочу сказать. что теория дается как то плохо когда я ее тупо учу, тем более с такой кучей разнообразной информации со старыми синтексами.
private раньше был теперь нет требуется, типо того((((

Comment: @Bulbash все это не надо учить, вам не экзамен сдавать. Нужно просто знать о всех основных возможностях  и понимать их ДО того, как начать писать код, а в процессе написания никто не запрещает "подглядывать". Иначе вы обречены на большое количество ошибок и начинаний заново, при этом результат обучения часто остаётся малоудовлитворительным  (так называемый говнокод).

Comment: Кстати, книга Филлипса - это не "пустая" нудная теория, обучение ведётся через разработку реального приложения с разбором по шагам, что и как происходит и почему так, а не иначе. То есть, вы пишите свое первое приложение под руководством опытного наставника, а не методом слепого тыкания, мало представляя, что же на самом деле происходит. В общем почитайте, это лучшее решение научиться интересно, быстро и качественно кодить, как бы с первых глав станет ясно, нужно вам это или нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, возьму в работу сейчас, а еще есть какая книга, второй прочитать после Филлипса?

Comment: @Bulbash Еще есть книга: Пол Дейтел "андроид для разработчиков" на том же принципе разработки реального приложения, но она послабее и постарее. Некоторым хорошо заходит из серии Head First.  Книга Д.Гриффитс "Программирование для Android" там в игровой манере подается материал, тоже с большим количеством примеров и заданий. В этой серии есть книга и по Java